# Python selenium download pdf with headless and plugins.always_open_pdf_externally

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I need to download a pdf, I use headless so the browser doesn't open, and the pdf is in a view, so I used the `"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally" parameter: True`.

To not render the browser I use the `options.add_argument ("- headless")` parameter.

If I comment on `options.add_argument ("- headless")` the pdf download usually happens, but if I leave it enabled it doesn't work.

How can I solve this problem?

parameters:

````
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

appState = {
    "recentDestinations": [
        {
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local"
        }
    ],
    "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
    "version": 2
}

profile = {"plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled": False, "name": "Chrome PDF Viewer"}], # Disable Chrome's PDF Viewer
               "download.extensions_to_open": "applications/pdf",
            #    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True,
               "printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState": json.dumps(appState)}

options.add_experimental_option("prefs", profile)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'D:\Mega\Raiz\Dados_brcaptura\chromedriver.exe')
print ("Headless Chrome Initialized")

params = {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': r'C:\Users\dieinimy\Downloads'}
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.setDownloadBehavior', params)```
````

Comment: Are you firing any events to download Pdf??I mean clicking on any button etc??

Comment: Yes I am, I use click ().
`WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".lupa-pdf"))).click()`

Comment: @DieinimyMaganha Headless chrome does not support for pdf viewer check [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1872)

Answer (score 0):

In order to fire on event on headless browser you have to set the window size.Because headless browser can't recognise where to click without window size.

```
 options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
 options.add_argument('--headless')
 options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080');
```

Comment: I put the settings below

Comment: These options work only if I comment the `options.add_argument ("- headless")`, then the PDF is downloaded.

Otherwise it doesn't download and it doesn't have any errors either.

Comment: You should removed your post from answer and post it in the question section.

Comment: OK, I did the removal

Comment: Before you clicked can you just check are you able to get the text of the button on headless mode.

Comment: Yes I can get it, but it still doesn't download if I use headless.

Comment: Maybe it's because the button is called a javascript, now comes the doubt, using headless lets it execute javascripts?